# Extract address/contact details from a text block with name and address?

Tags: java, android, street-address

I have a block of text that includes name, maybe company name, and address, and maybe email address. I want to extract the street address out of that, and preferably name and address.

This data is siphoned from multiple sources, so I have no idea about the actual formatting. It could be something like this

```
Company name, owner@domain.com
ATTN John Doe
care of Company Name
123 Street St
New York, NY 12345
US
123-456-7890
```

But any of those lines could be rearranged or missing (phone number could come first, no ATTN or c/o, etc). Also, this could be from any country.

The goal is to a) plug the address into the Google Maps API, and b) create a contact with as much information as possible.

Here is a random idea I had:

1. Take any line with an email address (can be found with a regex easily), store the email address and remove the line from further consideration.
2. Take any line with a phone number (digits only, and [-+()]), store that number, and remove the line from further consideration.
3. Take the last three lines and consider those the street address - plug them into Google Maps and hope for the best.

Obviously, that's a lot of juju magic. Is there a smarter approach? Are there are any libraries that have good regexes to look for street addresses of different countries?

Comment: @Nemi: Nope, although the app I needed it for is on the backburner. Still an interesting problem, would be nice to find a solution for it.

Comment: Best you can do for this problem is to train an entity resolution model

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your source. If you have control of how it arrives from your source, then you can do some formatting.

Comment: That's the problem - I don't. This is pulled from multiple sources that I have no control over.

Comment: Which sources? There might be a configuration option

Comment: In this particular case, the data is coming from WHOIS information. Obviously, I have no control over the sources, you get a chunk of data, and that's it.